# Array of Sequences in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read distinct values column wise in a data frame and store them in a Array of sequence

```
def getColumnDistinctValues(df: DataFrame, colNames:String): Unit = {
  val cols: Array[String] = colNames.split(',')
  cols.foreach(println) // print column names
  var colDistValues: Array[Seq[Any]] = null
  for (i <- 0 until cols.length) {
    colDistValues(i) = df.select(cols(i)).distinct.map(x => x.get(0)).collect   // read distinct values from each column
}
```

The assignment to colDistValues(i) doesn't work and always results in null pointer exception, what is the correct syntax to assign it the distinct values for each column?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to access the ith index of a null pointer (which you assign yourself), of course you'll get a `NullPointerException`. You don't need to initialize an `Array[T]` beforehand, let the returned collection do that for you:

```
val colDistValues: Array[Array[Any]] = 
  cols.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.map(x => x.get(0)).collect)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the code , now I get this error :Error:(42, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Array[Any]]
 required: Seq[Seq[Any]]
      cols.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.map(x => x.get(0)).collect)

Comment: yes it worked for me too, suppose I want to variable to be Seq[Seq[Any]], how do I type cast? I believe Seq should be better in terms of performance

Comment: @Rani Do: `cols.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.map(x => x.get(0).toSeq).collect.toSeq`

Comment: Thankyou very much, this has really helped me

Comment: Thankyou very much for your expertise, would appreciate if you can take a look at my other question and provide your inputs.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853602/efficient-way-of-using-for-loops-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

You are initialising the `colDistValues` to null.

Replace

```
var colDistValues: Array[Seq[Any]] = null
```

with

```
var colDistValues: Array[Seq[Any]] = Array.ofDim[Seq[Any]](cols.length)
```